# do code if current url = value

Tags: conditional-tags

The [Google Content Experiments installation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-content-experiments/installation/) is not working for me.  [I add the code in the header, but nothing is output](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-content-experiments/installation/).

So, I've added the Google Analytics experiment code manually into the header.  The only problem is the theme is shared between network sites.  So I want to only insert the code into the header on the condition that the current URL = {value}.

I know I can use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), but if I use is_page, this might fire accidently on another network site.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $wp;
$current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );
$is_specific_network = stripos( $current_url, 'specific_domain_or_ip_address' );
if( $is_specific_network !== false ) {
    // do the task below

} else {
    // do something else or leave it blank

}
```

N.B. : You need to replace the IP address or specific domain name above to distinguish the network.

===================  OR  ======================

```
<?php
$current_site = get_current_site();
$current_domain = $current_site->domain;
if( $current_domain == 'something' ) {
    // do something
}
?>
```

You can use anything from this data being returned:

```
(object) 
An object containing details of the site currently being viewed. Details are represented in the following public variables: 

id 
    (integer) ID of the site currently being viewed. 
domain 
    (string) Domain of the site currently being viewed. 
path 
    (string) Path of the site currently being viewed. 
site_name 
    (string) Title of the site currently being viewed.
```

Refer: http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_site

Comment: Beautiful.  Note: I had to ensure I included the **www.** to ensure a match.

Comment: The Codex does not describe what **path** is.

Comment: Path provides you the absolute directory path for the setup. Like in *NIX : /var/www/...

Comment: Unfortunately the Google Content Experiment code is being run on all pages of the website, as all pages have a match for the domain.